# Should we prevent from calling func within checking condition of a Python loop?

Tags: python, while-loop, conditional-statements, compiler-optimization

We often encounter such a situation that we need to check if a loop should be terminated, while some terminating condition comes from a function.

If the result of the func changes during the loop, it's no doubt we have to call the func every time.
When the result of the func is a constant during the loop, it looks like better to store the result with a variable to prevent from calling repeatedly the func and getting a same result.

My question is "**Does Python interpreters optimize such problems for us?**"
If so, we don't need to do it manually like this:

```
end = len(data)
# many other codes are here
while position < end:
    do_something(position)
```

Instead we can keep codes simple and more readable:

```
# whatever codes here don't influence the readability of the loop 
while position < len(data):
    do_something(position)
```

Comment: No, it is impossible for the interpreter to tell if the returning value of a function is going to remain constant throughout the loop. In some other programming languages such as Ruby, we have the `||=` operator so that we can initialize a constant with a function call and use the constant on the same line, e.g. `while position < (end ||= data.length()):`.

Comment: I dunno, looking at your 2nd, more readable version of the code, I'd **assume** that `len(data)` is **not** going to be a constant within the loop.  That's why you are calling it on repeat.  If `len(data)` was a constant, you'd do performance 101 and keep it outside the loop, as in your first version.  You can always assign `end = len(data)` right before the loop, not before *many codes are here*.  Now, if data mostly doesn't change much and the func is expensive you could maybe memoize it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The interpreter does not optimize this for you due to the simple reason, it cannot...

python is a dynamic interpreted language which allows some funky scenarios.
for example, this snippet is 100% valid:

```py
while position < len(data):    
    do_something(position)
    
    def len(v):
        return data.__len__() + 42
```

each time the `position < len(data)` expression is interpreted, the meaning of `len` is different.

My advice would be - don't worry about it.
The `len` function's time penalty is either a drop in the ocean in comparison to `do_something` or the whole thing is probably quick enough.

When you get to a scenarion it does matter - solve the specific problem in a way that would suit the specific case (hint: `lru_cache` can come in handy in many cases!).

Comment: upvtd for the lru_cache based memoization hint (although it brings in an element of extra-cleverness that would be best reserved to cases that really would benefit).

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No, but we can use [walrus operator](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions) to achieve similar goal. However, walrus operator just makes your code neat but won't save the stack call cost. Theoretically, if you're pursuing the best performance, `end = len(data)` is the best choice.

Analysis:

```py
import dis
data = [1, 3, 4]
def test1():
    position = 0
    end = len(data)
    while position < end:
        # do something
        position += 1
def test2():
    position = 0
    while position < len(data):
        # do something
        position += 1
dis.dis(test1)
print("------")
dis.dis(test2)
```

Output:

```
  6           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
  2             STORE_FAST               0 (position)

  7           4 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (len)
              6 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (data)
              8 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             10 STORE_FAST               1 (end)

  8     >>   12 LOAD_FAST                0 (position)
             14 LOAD_FAST                1 (end)
             16 COMPARE_OP               0 (<)
             18 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       30

 10          20 LOAD_FAST                0 (position)
             22 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
             24 INPLACE_ADD
             26 STORE_FAST               0 (position)
             28 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           12
        >>   30 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             32 RETURN_VALUE
-----
 12           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
              2 STORE_FAST               0 (position)

 13     >>    4 LOAD_FAST                0 (position)
              6 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (len)
              8 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (data)
             10 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             12 COMPARE_OP               0 (<)
             14 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       26

 15          16 LOAD_FAST                0 (position)
             18 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
             20 INPLACE_ADD
             22 STORE_FAST               0 (position)
             24 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            4
        >>   26 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             28 RETURN_VALUE
```

As we can see, `test2()` will does

```
              6 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (len)
              8 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (data)
             10 CALL_FUNCTION            1
```

every loop, while `test1()` only does

```
             14 LOAD_FAST                1 (end)
```

By using walrus operator, the function and the output are shown below, respectively:

```
import dis
data = [1, 3, 4]
def walrus():
    position = 0
    while position < (end := len(data)):
        # do something
        position += 1
dis.dis(walrus)
```

```
 18           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
              2 STORE_FAST               0 (position)

 19     >>    4 LOAD_FAST                0 (position)
              6 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (len)
              8 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (data)
             10 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             12 DUP_TOP
             14 STORE_FAST               1 (end)
             16 COMPARE_OP               0 (<)
             18 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       30

 21          20 LOAD_FAST                0 (position)
             22 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
             24 INPLACE_ADD
             26 STORE_FAST               0 (position)
             28 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            4
        >>   30 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             32 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: You provide neither any analysis nor any suggestion on how one can use the walrus operator to achieve the OP's goal.

Comment: @blhsing misclicking the submit before I finished the analysis.

Comment: Not really.  walrus is only useful when your loop wants to do something with the result of the function call in the while condition.  if if *do something* did something with `end`.

Comment: @JLPeyret agree

Answer (score 0):

Python interpreters don't optimize such problems. In this case, the value of `len(data)` is not cached and will be calculated on each iteration of this while loop. So, you are better off using your first code block above where you store this value somewhere.